# Displaying PNG files in android (images being resized)

Tags: android, png

Im dragging my images into the drawable-hdpi folder in Eclipse and when I load them in the program they are 2/3rd the original size. (my 500x150 .png is being loaded as a 333x100 .png)
Any advice on how I should be creating/loading images for android?

```
private Bitmap mGrass;
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
mGrass = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.grass, options);

canvas.drawBitmap(mGrass, 0, 0, noPaint);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats the AVD[Android Virtual Device]'s DPI you are using? If the DPI is 160, then please put your images into mdpi, hdpi for phones with DPI more than 240

Comment: Thanks! I also had my AVD set up wrong which only lead to further confusion.